# PHP - Pagination: $_POST or $_GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination

I'm developing a search system(multiple filters) that uses pagination with php.
At first i was using the method POST with the main form. But, using POST i was unable to keep the pagination. Reason: when the user search by name, for example, as he clicks in the next pages the query get lost and return to the first page.
To fix this i use GET method instead.
But using GET, the url gets the parameters. And the users don't want that.

Example:

```
http://mysearch.com/search.php?name=joe&id=1
```

I just want to be

```
http://mysearch.com/search.php
```

I tried this workaround:

```
if(typeof window.history.pushState == 'function') {
        window.history.pushState({}, "Hide", "http://mysearch.com/search.php");
}
```

But when i hit the "Previous Page/Back" in the browser, the URL with the parameters come back either.

Is there a solution for this? Use GET or POST with pagination and the parameters does not shows in the URL?

Comment: Why wouldn't the users want that? Most (if not all...) search engines work that way and by doing that your visitors will be able to share and bookmark links.

Comment: Level of users, as they told me. That search, as i said, have multiple filters. A user with permission "a" could search by name, but the user with permission "b" couldn't. Even if the field won't appear in the page, and int the url, their are concern that some other user will modify the url putting the &name parameter and will succeed in the search query.

Comment: The backend should make sure that users can only do what they're allowed to, regardless of the request they send.

Comment: That was exactly what i told them. users, right? :(

Comment: Can't argue with that :-)

Comment: If it possible, you can encode your url with shar1, or random string instead of the actual id or username

Comment: My advice: Leave your pagination details in the URL. Don't hide them. When people traverse through their history or bookmark something and you've gone out of your way to mangle the URL, you erase this important information. If you wanted clean URLs you wouldn't have `.php` in the URL in the first place, so until that's gone the rest is irrelevant. If you need to restrict functionality, your server-side code should take care of that. Hiding the URL parameters does nothing.

Comment: Thank you, i heard ya. I'll take your advices and talk to the users again. Hopefully they will understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can paginate with $_POST just as easily as with $_GET and without SESSION variables/cookies, you just need to pass the pagination variables as hidden values in your HTML form.

eg - for two buttons, one of which takes you to previous page, and one to next:

```
//prev button
<form action="paginate.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="prev" value="0"/> 
    <input type="submit" value="Go to previous page"/>
</form>

//next button
<form action="paginate.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="2"/> 
    <input type="submit" value="Go to next page"/>
</form>

//search form
<form action="paginate.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="prev" value="0"/>         
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="2"/> 
    <input type="text" name="search" value="User input goes here"/> 
    <input type="submit" value="Search the database"/>
</form>
```

The disadvantage is that POST will give 'page expired' errors when using the browser back button (but not the HTML buttons), which is not great. For that reason I'd prefer $_GET, and also because you can bookmark $_GET queries, but not $_POST.

Comment: Thanks @fred2. In my case i'm using "<First 1 2 3 4 5 6 Last>". Those number of pages is created dynamically according to the num of rows that select return. I think i will have to keep with GET..

Comment: Yeah - it doesn't make very much sense to use that approach and NOT use GET. You could do it with POST, but the way to do it would be probably be to use JavaScript and assign onclick events to each of the numbers, which then submitted the variables by POST dynamically. But that's really banging you head against a brick wall without reason.

Comment: Hahahaha got it. Won't do that. I'll stick with the GET method. Thanks!